# Try/Catch, Windows Service and Environment.Exit

Tags: c#, azure, windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have found very interesting behavior in my windows service application on Windows Azure Server 2012 R2 VM. My windows service that call,

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((_) => DoWork());
```

In DoWork,

```
    private static void DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            // Do all work
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log(ex);
        }
    }
```

The call to `Environment.Exit(0)` leting the process to crashed. No log in event viewer and no further info. Just `process unexpectedly terminated`. Why try/catch is not working there? Is this is expected behavior for Windows Service app.

Comment: You shouldn't be closing your app from a thread like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why try/catch is not working there?

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),

> If **Exit** is called from a try or finally block, the code in any catch
>   block does not execute.

@RufusL is right in saying that you shouldn't close your app like that.

Perhaps there is a more graceful way of closing your app.
Like, maybe, calling a closing event or maybe you could just try removing that `Environment.Exit(0)` code and 'let things be' :D

Comment: I am not doing this. Just asking why my process is crashing instead of closing the app as MSDN is saying that it will close the app. If it is throwing an error then the catch should be called.

Comment: @user960567 please read my answer. 

If Exit is called from a try or finally block, **the code in any catch block does not execute.**

There is no way to change this. Unless you are going to Microsoft and telling them to change the way their API works.

What usually happens is the opposite: **the developer adapts to what Microsoft has provided** or **uses a different function or workaround.**

You cannot force Microsoft to change their functions just for you.

Comment: The MSDN link never says that if exception happen then?

Comment: @user960567 I donot understand your sentence